# Twitter Bootstrap popover display in wrong place

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have button that when I click on it I get "pop up window" (use boostrap modal) with data. I used twitter boostrap tooltip and everything works fine. when I decide replace the tooltip by popover I get some strange problems. first of all I want popover show up when I hover a link but it appear only when I click on the link. secondary the popover appears on the main window and don't disappear no metter what I try. I just want him appear on the boostrap modal like my last tooltip.

this is my link:

```
<a href="#" class="blob" data-html="true" data-triger="hover" data-original-title="A Title" data-content="bla bla bla">link</a>
```

js:

```
$('.blob').popover();
```

how can I fix it? what wrong?

Comment: should that be `data-trigger` attribute on the `<a>` tag?

Comment: it possible write "data-trigger" attribute in the <a> tag, another way is write it as part of js $('.blob').popover({trigger: "hover"});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the data-trigger attribute isn't working, but passing the option using the JS initialization parameter makes it behave as you intend:

```
$('.blob').popover({trigger: "hover"});
```

jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dcasadevall/S8sXQ/1/

Comment: thanks it works well, but not in modal so I just add z-index:5000;

Answer (score 1):

You spelled trigger incorrectly, should be:

```
<a href="#" class="blob" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="A Title" data-content="bla bla bla">link</a>
```

With that corrected it works fine in jsfiddle for me.

Comment: thanks it works too, you right! I spell it wrong. but it's not works on the modal (pop up) so I add z-index:5000; sorry that I don't mark your answer as a correct. the only reason is because dcasadevall answer first.